# how to install documentation of iOS 5 sdk in xcode 4.2 without internet?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I don't have internet on my mac how can I install documentation for iOS 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the documentation file on other system (which have internet connection) from this link

http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20111012/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_0.iOSLibrary.xar

then uncompress this .xar file at - /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/

Update: here is the links for other documentation files for offline install -

[Apple iOS Documentation V 5.0](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20111012/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_0.iOSLibrary.xar)
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.2 (XCode 4)](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20101122/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.Xcode4.xar)
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.2 (XCode < 4?)](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20101122/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.xar) 
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.3](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20110309/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_3.iOSLibrary.xar)
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.3](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20110720/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_3.iOSLibrary.xar)
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.1](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20100908/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_1.iOSLibrary.xar)
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.1 (XCode 4)](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20100908/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_1.iOSLibrary.Xcode4_0.xar)
[Apple iOS Documentation V 4.0](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20100803/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_0.iOSLibrary.xar)
[Mac OS Lion Core Reference](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20111012/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.CoreReference.xar)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.2, the iOS 5 documentation is already pre-installed... press cmd+shift+2 and open up the organizer.  It will be under the 'Documentation' tab.

Comment: If you updated to ios 5.0.1 the documentation just disappears, and it has to be downloaded again.
EDIT: Updated to 4.2.1 (xcode), not to 5.0.1

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't had that problem, and I'm on 5.0.1 right now.  I wonder if he's using OSX lion, because I have Xcode 4.2.1

Comment: no documentation is not present in default xcode 4.2... if you check the size of the installer .dmg you'll notice its under 2GB instead of previous (xcode 3.2's) around 4gb installer file

Comment: Sorry, I just told you wrong. It was not updating to 5.0.1, it was updating xcode to 4.2.1. I edited my previous comment to fix that. When I first installed xcode from the app store (version 4.2) it had all the documentation. When updated to 4.2.1, the documentation was just gone. I had to access it via web. I had to download it from the app menu.

Comment: Again, interesting.  THe only thing I had to download again when I ran the installer was the iOS 4.3 simulator.